# extract language from a web page with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

For example I have

`<html lang="en"> ...... web page </html>`

I want to extract the string "en" with Jsoup.

I tried with selector and attribute without success.

```
Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element taglang = htmlDoc.select("html").first();
System.out.println(taglang.text());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want to get value of `lang` *attribute*. In that case you can use [`attr("nameOfAttribute")`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr(java.lang.String)) like

```
System.out.println(taglang.attr("lang"));
```