# Find language of a site loaded in my webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I have a webview where external url will be launched and loaded in the webview.
So, I want to find what language the webpage is? is it possible in android webview?

Answer (score 0):

After scanning the documentation it doesn't look like there's an explicit method in the `WebView` class that allows you to retrieve the language used by the web page.

An alternative way of finding out the language of a web page would be to download the raw HTML content of the page using the [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) library and parsing it for the `lang` attribute. However, this would obviously require that the owner of the page specified that attribute when creating the page.

Here's a snippet of how you can use JSoup to get the raw HTML content of the page you're trying to load:

```
Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

Then, to parse for the `lang` attribute (which is used to specify the natural language of the content found on the web page), you would do this ([credit to this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390378/extract-language-from-a-web-page-with-jsoup)):

```
Element html = htmlDoc.select("html").first();
String langAttr = htmlDoc.attr("lang"); //check that this isn't null before using it
```

Hope this helps. But to answer your original question - no, the `WebView` class doesn't have an explicit method to obtain the language of a web page included out of the box.